# Java program is blank

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar

I'm currently learning Java. Or at least looking into it. I figured since it is a General Purpose programming language it would be good to learn since I could even put it to use in Web Development.

I followed [this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html) to build a little mini calculator for adding. It was my first time doing something like this so it was pretty awesome to me. I was using the NetBeans GUI tool to do this. Everything seemed to be going fine until I Cleaned and Built the project. The .jar file didn't load when I double clicked it so I couldn't open the program using that.

I decided to just click on the Run button in the NetBeans program. The program came up but the window was blank:

[image: Netbeans and the blank program]

Here you can see what the form should look like and what I actually get.

I've also tried executing the .jar file in the command prompt using:

```
java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar
```

But I have no idea how the file system works in the command prompt so I always get an error.

So my question is, does anybody know for the reasoning of why my .jar files are not working as expected and is there a solution for this?

### Edit: My Code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package my.numberaddition;

/**
 *
 * @author Shawn
 */
public class NumberAdditionUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NumberAdditionUI
     */
    public NumberAdditionUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Number Addition", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION));

        jLabel1.setText("First Number");

        jLabel2.setText("Second Number");

        jLabel3.setText("Result");

        jButton1.setText("Clear");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Add");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Exit");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 77, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                                .addComponent(jTextField3))))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2))))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 332, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 216, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextField1.setText("");
        jTextField2.setText("");
        jTextField3.setText("");
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // First we define float variables.
        float num1, num2, result;
        // We have to parse the text to a type float.
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
       // Now we can perform the addition.
        result = num1+num2;
        // We will now pass the value of result to jTextField3.
        // At the same time, we are going to
        // change the value of result from a float to a string.
        jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NumberAdditionUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NumberAdditionUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  That will be much more useful than screenshots of an empty GUI and your IDE.

Comment: so the problem is the screenshot or the code? :)

Comment: The problem is the code.  Post an SSCCE.

Comment: Well I just figured someone could tell me why my `.jar` files aren't executing as it should. There are no errors while compiling so I figure the code is fine.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How do I post? All I see is a bunch of text.

Comment: *"There are no errors while compiling so I figure the code is fine."*  There are 1001 errors that can happen at run-time.  Most of them do not even throw an error or exception.  *"How do I post? All I see is a bunch of text."*  Use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: I added my source code for the project.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay, I didn't know that. I just started this yesterday..

Comment: There is something wrong with the 2nd layout.  If I swap it for a `BorderLayout` and explicitly add the `jPanel2` it shows up.

Answer (score 2):

The `JPanel` `jPanel2` has not been added either the horizontal or vertical groups of the ContentPane's `SpringLayout`

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 332, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    .addComponent(jPanel2)
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 216, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    .addComponent(jPanel2)
);
```

Comment: So where exactly do I add this?

Comment: Do a search on `332` in the code..  BTW - this is one of the (many) reasons) we advise to *avoid* the 'GUI designer' until a firm grasp of layouts is gained.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I can't edit that part of the script. It is locked

Comment: Shouldn't the GUI designer automatically add the component though? Especially if its in code I can't edit.

Comment: It should. Something may have occurred to detach the panel from the frame. (TBH using Netbeans GUI builder is not a great way to become familiar with the code)

Comment: *"I can't edit that part of the script. It is locked"*  Stop using the D'n'D GUI designer & start learning how to write GUI code.

Comment: @Reimeus Thank you for saying that, I didn't have it in the `jframe`. I didn't know I had to do that. What should I be using besides Netbeans?

Comment: Any IDE will do (I use Eclipse). Start coding by hand using the standard [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).